# Can't get if/else function to work with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, onclick, radio-button

I have looked all over this site (and Google) for an answer to my problem but I can only seem to find bits and pieces, nothing specific.

I am primarily playing around with JavaScript and HTML but am *not* trying to use jquery right now.

So, with that said, this is what I'm trying to do: I would like the user to enter two numbers, select an operation (add, subtract, multiply, divide) out of a list of four radio buttons, and then click a button which is linked to a function that does the math and then presents it in a text box on the page. How would I do this using only HTML and JavaScript? I have gotten everything to work up until the point I add the radio buttons.

The code is as follows:

```
<script>
function operationForm (form) {
    var x = document.operationForm.getElementById("numberOne");
    var y = document.operationForm.getElementById("numberTwo");
    var operation;
    var answer;
    if (document.operationForm.addSelect.checked === true) {
        answer = x + y;
        document.operationForm.answerBox.value = answer;
    } else if (document.operationForm.subtractSelect.checked === true) {
        answer = x - y;
        document.operationForm.answerBox.value = answer;

    } else if (document.operationForm.multiplySelect.checked === true) {
        answer = x * y;
        document.operationForm.answerBox.value = answer;

    } else(document.operationForm.divideSelect.checked === true) {
        answer = x / y;
        document.operationForm.answerBox.value = answer;

    }
}
</script>

<h1>Let's calculate!</h1>

<form name="operationForm">
<p>
    <label>Enter two numbers, select an operation, and then click the   button below.
        <p>
            <label>Number One:
                <input type="text" name='numbers' id="numberOne">
                <br>
                <br>Number Two:
                <input type="text" name='numbers' id="numberTwo">
                <p>
                    <input type="radio" name="operations" id="addSelect" value=''>Add
                    <input type="radio" name="operations" id="subtractSelect" value=''>Subtract
                    <input type="radio" name="operations" id="multiplySelect" value=''>Multiply
                    <input type="radio" name="operations" id="divideSelect" value=''>Divide
                    <label>
                        <p>
                            <input type="button" value=" Calculate " onClick='operationForm(form);'>
                            <p>
                                <label>Your answer is:
                                    <input type="text" name="answerBox">
```

If anyone has any fixes or can point me in the right direction of the correct syntax for handling radio buttons, functions linking to them, and onClick events linking to those functions, it would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing the `<input type="button" value=" Calculate " onClick='operationForm(form);'>` with `<input type="button" value=" Calculate " onClick='operationForm();'>`. Next change the function `operationForm` to accept no parameters. Then add id to your input answer box. Next for each if statement in the function use the elementById function to get the radios and the answerBox. For example, the first if should be 
`if (document.getElementById("addSelect").checked) {
        answer = x + y;
        document.getElementById("answerBox").value = answer;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function operationForm(){

    var form = document.forms['operation_form'];

    var x = form['numberOne'].value*1;
    var y = form['numberTwo'].value*1;

    var operation = null;
    var answer = null;

    if (form['addSelect'].checked == true) {
        answer = x + y;
    } else if (form['subtractSelect'].checked == true) {
        answer = x - y;
    } else if (form['multiplySelect'].checked == true) {
        answer = x * y;
    } else if (form['divideSelect'].checked == true) {
        answer = x / y;
    }

    form['answerBox'].value = answer;

}
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="operation_form">
    <label>Enter two numbers, select an operation, and then click the   button below.</label>
    <br/>
    <label>Number One:</label><input type="number" name='numberOne' />
    <br/>
    <br/>Number Two:</label><input type="number" name='numberTwo' />
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="operations" id="addSelect" value='' />Add
    <input type="radio" name="operations" id="subtractSelect" value='' />Subtract
    <input type="radio" name="operations" id="multiplySelect" value='' />Multiply
    <input type="radio" name="operations" id="divideSelect" value='' />Divide
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value=" Calculate " onclick="operationForm();" />
    <br/>
    <label>Your answer is:</label><input type="text" name="answerBox">
</form>
```

**Fixes between this and your example:**

There are a ton of things wrong with the code you provided.  I will update this answer shortly with as many as I can remember.

### Update:

Please remember this is meant to be helpful and not punishing. So keep in mind that while listening to the attached feedback, I want you to learn this stuff.

**Notes on your HTML:**

**1.)** The biggest problem is none of the `<label>` elements have closing`</label>` tags.
Although, none of your html elements have any closing tags.
This will group all of the elements inside one big parent `<label>`.
So when the browser auto-closes the unclosed tags at the end of the document, this causes a hodgepodge of mixed up child elements. Close your elements.

**2.)** The first two text boxes have the same `name="numbers"` attribute. You can only do that with radio type inputs.

**3.)** Your `<form>` `name=""` attribute can NOT have the same name as the JavaScript function you are trying to call.  They are stored in the same browser namespace so it causes an error.

**Notes on your JavaScript:**

**1.)** Your `checked === true` is an exact comparison.  This will almost never evaluate to be truthful. Use `checked == true`, or better yet, just use `if( my_element.checked ){}`.  Sometimes `.checked` will equal a string like this: `.checked = 'checked'`.  So even though `'checked'==true` it will never be truthful for `'checked'===true`. The `===` means **Exactly Equal**.  So only `true===true`.

**2.)** Your `var x = document.opera.. ... .mberOne");` will store the whole `<input>` element into the `x` variable.  You need to have `...mberOne").value;` so just the **value** of the `<input>` is stored, not the whole html element.

**3.)** The only object that has a `getElementById()` method is the `document`.  You can't use that from a document `form` object.

**4.)** You have to convert your `x` any `y` input values to numbers.  If not, `5 + 5` will give you `55` instead of `10` because they are treated as strings.  I multiplied them by `* 1` to do that. I also changed the `<input` `type='text'` attribute to `type='number'` just to be safe.

**5.)** You can assign your `answerBox.value` just one time at the end of the function instead of doing it once per `if(){}` bracket.  It will work the same but it's just much more readable.

**6.)** I used the syntax of `form['numberOne']` instead of `form.numberOne` but they both work the same. It is referencing the element `name` (not necessarily the `id`) as it exists inside the form. `<form>` is the only object that lets you do this, whereas a `<div>` or `<p>` does not.

Comment: Anything you can provide is appreciated. 

So, to clarify, the brackets behind form (the form['numberOne']) is basically saying "look inside the form, find the element with the id of "numberOne" and obtain it's value. What is the *1?

Comment: To answer your comment specifically.  Yes, your statement is basically correct.  "look inside the form, find the element with the `id`/`name` of `"numberOne"`."  That part gets you the whole element.  To get the value of that element, you need only to add `.value` at the end of it.  Lastly, the `*1`. To explain this, usually the `.value` property is provided as a text String. But you need to use it as a Number.  The `*1` will convert a String to a Number if possible. It will cause an error if not possible.

Comment: Your commentary is very much welcome and appreciated. It is frustrating knowing what you want but not having all the pieces to get there. Thank you for taking the time to provide more specific answers to the problems I was having in that code.

Comment: It's my pleasure. I'm happy that you found it useful and especially that you read through it afterward to digest it.  Many people just look for a working answer but don't take the time to understand the changes made to get it working.